# Running a script that's requires password in between

Tags: shell, passwords

I'm running a script that copies files from another server.... It's prompting for a password of that server... Every time I need to enter the password manually... So s there any way to automate this?

scp root@ip:file_location destination

**Note** for security purposes I was not supposed to use password less login, or ssh

Comment: scp uses ssh in the background, so it uses the same authentication (e.g., ssh keys)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use sshpass which takes the password from an evironment variable named "SSHPASS" if switch -e is provided. So you can use something like:

```
export SSHPASS=<yourpw>
sshpass -e scp <sourcefile> user@ip:<targetpath/filename>
```

But of course it still uses ssh underneath, like Sergiy explained in the comment.